# how to implement sectioned headers in custom array adapter?

Tags: java, android, listview, header, selection

How can I have section headers in my custom list adapter that separates the list items by it's date (created field) in my following code ?

This is my custom adapter code

```
private class MyCustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<ReportItem> 
{
    private ArrayList<ReportItem> stateList;

    public MyCustomAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,ArrayList<ReportItem> stateList) 
    {
        super(context, textViewResourceId, stateList);
        this.stateList = new ArrayList<ReportItem>();
        this.stateList.addAll(stateList);
    }

    private class ViewHolder 
    {
        TextView title;
        TextView city;
        TextView category;
        TextView created;
        TextView tags;

    }

    @SuppressLint("InflateParams")
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
    {

        ViewHolder holder = null;

        Log.v("ConvertView", String.valueOf(position));

        if (convertView == null) 
        {
            LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) c.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

            convertView = vi.inflate(R.layout.reports_list_item, null);

            holder = new ViewHolder();

            holder.title = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
            holder.city = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
            holder.category = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView3);
            holder.created = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView4);
            holder.tags = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView5);

            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } 

        else 
        {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        ReportItem county_obj = reportsListO.get(position);

        holder.title.setText(removeSpecialChars(county_obj.getTitleP()));
        holder.city.setText(removeSpecialChars(county_obj.getCity()));
        holder.category.setText(removeSpecialChars(county_obj.getCategoryP()));
        holder.created.setText(editTimeFormat(county_obj.getCreatedP()));
        holder.tags.setText(removeSpecialChars(county_obj.getTags()));


        return convertView;
    }

}
```

Comment: Did you try to Google it ? You'll find so many tutorials on very first page.

Comment: yeah , i found alot of tutorial for a simple adapter

but does not work on my custom adapter :(

Comment: What's the issue ? Look at this tutorial:
http://sunil-android.blogspot.com/2013/08/section-header-listview-in-android.html